# Why is my forkJoin subscription not reached while the subscriptions work independently?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, subscription, fork-join

I have two observables which I want to merge within the `forkJoin` method from `rxjs`. Executing the observables independently works, but using `forkJoin` it does not reach the `pipe finalize/subscribe` method.

> My.component.ts

```
....
const req1 = this.userService.getUser(this.loggedInUser.userId);
const req2 = this.boardGames$;
this.subscriptions$ = forkJoin([req1, req2])
  .pipe(
    finalize(() => {
      console.log('pipe'); // Is not reached
    })
  )
  .subscribe(([obj1, obj2]) => {
    console.log('subscribe'); // Is not reached
  }, err => console.log(err), ()=>console.log('compl'));
req1.subscribe((aa) => console.log(aa)); // This is logged
req2.subscribe((bb) => console.log(bb)); // This is logged
....
```

I am using `Angularfire2` for requests. I am not sure if this can be an issue, because independently the subscriptions work.
`import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';`

What is it that I am missing here?

Comment: this is because I want to unsubscribe on the destroy of the component. Unfortunatelly that does not help

Comment: This also is not printing anything

Comment: Strange. I am not able to replicate your issue, I've used the same code. Any errors on the console? Could you replicate this in a stackblitz?

Comment: I am not familiair with stackblitz so I am not sure. Maybe good to mention that the requests that I have make use of Angularfire2; `import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';`

Comment: Hmm, could be coz of that as normal http calls using `HttpClientModule` work fine for me.

Comment: Stackblitz is like an online editor where you can replicate the issue by writing your code there and then sharing the url. [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)

Comment: One of your source Observables `req1` or `req2` never completes so `forkJoin()` won't emit anything

Comment: @martin When I remove one of the forkJoin requests it still does not reach one of the logs. I tried both already.

Comment: Then it looks like both never complete or never emit.

Comment: @martin Event though the last two lines do work?

Comment: @Klyner Yes, because when Observable emits doesn't mean it completes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forkJoin` emits only when all observables completes. I can't see the rest of your code (for example what is `boardGames$` observable). Most likely you are using observables that won't complete after first emission, which is intended behavior of `AngularFirestore` since most commonly you subscribe to changes in the database (Firebase).

Use `combineLatest` if you need to get latest values when some observable emits. Keep in mind that it will start to emit only when each of the source observables emitted.

```
combineLatest([
    this.userService.getUser(this.loggedInUser.userId), 
    this.boardGames$
]).subscribe(([user, boardGames]) => {
     // Don't forget to unsubscribe
});
```

Use `merge` ir you want to merge observables into one observable. It would work in your current case. Like this:

```
merge(
  this.userService.getUser(this.loggedInUser.userId).pipe(map(entity => ({entity, type: 'user'}))),
  this.boardGames$.pipe(map(entity => ({entity, type: 'boardGames'})))
).subscribe(({entity, type}) => {
    // Don't forget to unsubscribe
})
```

With `forkJoin` you can achieve it like this:

```
const req1 = this.userService.getUser(this.loggedInUser.userId).pipe(take(1));
const req2 = this.boardGames$.pipe(take(1));
this.subscriptions$ = forkJoin([req1, req2]).subscribe(() => {
    // I will complete after both observables emits.
});
```

Note that you would still need to handle subscription even if use `take(1)` since in case if some observable never emits and component is destroyed, you would have a memory leak. There is [awesome library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngneat/until-destroy) for handling subscriptions without boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

`forkjoin()` needs both your subscriptions to **complete** in order to actually join them. So if either of your subscriptions don't complete then  `forkjoin()` will never be reached. If you are using firebase your observables don't complete.

If your subscriptions don't complete and you need a stream from both observables then you should try out `combineLatest()` instead. This takes in two active subscriptions and once each subscription emits a value will join the values in a single subscription and continue to emit values until completed.

[Here is a link for combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest)

If you only need to check is the user is valid before making a call to firebase then try `switchMap()`. This will switch your user observable into your boardgame observable and you will only be dealing with the boardgame observable.